# setTimeout vs setInterval again

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

So I know that there are differences between `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, but consider these two code examples:

```
function myFunction(){
   setTimeout('myFunction();', 100);
   doSomething();
}
setTimeout('myFunction();', 100);
```

and

```
function myFunction(){
   doSomething();
}
setInterval('myFunction();', 100);
```

Note that in the first example I call `setTimeout` at the begining of the function and then I `doSomething`. Therefore there is no extra delay from `doSomething()`. Does that mean that those two examples do exactly the same? Or is there even more subtle difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're functionally about the same, but there are differences. One difference is in how browsers handle it if `doSomething` takes longer than the interval. With `setInterval`, at least some browsers will just *skip* the next interval if `doSomething` is still running. So if you use 100ms as you have, and `doSomething` takes 110 ms to run, the next run won't happen until 90ms later (of course, all of these times are approximate).

Another difference is that with the `setTimeout`, you'll get a new handle every time, whereas with `setInterval` you get one handle.

Another difference with your examples as given is that in the `setTimeout` example, you're firing up a JavaScript parser/compiler *every time*, whereas with `setInterval` you're only firing up the parser/compiler once. But this difference shouldn't matter, because you shouldn't be doing that at all — see below.

But subtleties aside, what you have there is functionally the same.

---

**Side note**: It's not best practice to pass strings into either `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Instead, pass in a function reference:

```
// setTimeout
function myFunction(){
   setTimeout(myFunction, 100);
   doSomething();
}
setTimeout(myFunction, 100);

// setInterval
function myFunction(){
   doSomething();
}
setInterval(myFunction, 100);
```

Passing in a string fires up a JavaScript parser and does the same thing as `eval`. It should be avoided whenever possible (and it's almost always possible).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Of course using function reference is better. But this gave me an idea. If you run `setTimeout` with string then it is possible to pass variable to the function, for example `setTimeout('myFunction('+i+');', 100);`. This variable can be evaluated every time `myFunction` is called (locally). I don't see the way to do the same with `setInterval` except for the global variables (not passed to `myFunction`). So there's another difference.

Comment: @freakish: True. I wouldn't do it that way, but you're right that it's another difference between them if you use strings.

Comment: +1 well written & detailed answer, glad you're not gone for good TJ :)

Comment: @alex: Cheers, that's very kind. I'm probably contributing at about 10% my former level, just cannot get on-board with Atwood's vision for community management.

Answer (score 1):

T.J. Crowder explained the main differences, one other more subtle could appear (I change the time scale as it's easier to explain) :

Lets plot the difference with a very big timeout time : 1 Day. You call both methods at 00:00 on Day 1 and let it run for 1 year...

1 Year latter your method called by setInterval will execute at 00:00 + some milliseconds (because you may not be the only one asking for the processors to do things at this exact moment and the OS timers have granularity anyway).

But your setTimeout method will occur latter, maybe around 00:01 because each day it would have been called a little after the requested time and requested to be called the next day at the same time...

*PS: It could also be called before the requested time in some cases but more often than not it run after :-D*