# Confused with set timeout

Tags: javascript

I'm really confused how these work...the timeout does not seem to keep running it calls `begin_anim` once and then thats it....

So am hoping someone can see where i went wrong and explain how I implement this?

This is my code:

```
//test data:
//type = 'up';
//div = document.getElementById('theid');
//marginL = -400;

function timeout_begin(type,div,marginL){   
    setTimeout(begin_anim(type,div,marginL),1000);
}

function begin_anim(type,div,marginL){
    if(type == 'up'){
        if(marginL >= '-200'){ 
                if(marginL > '-200'){ 
                    div.style.marginLeft = '-200px';
                }
            return false;
        }
    marginL += 2;
    div.style.marginLeft = marginL+'px';


    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: How would you implement "what"? "and then thats it" --- it's not a error explanation

Comment: the set time out .. because it does not run. I never said i had an error there isn't a syntax error.

Comment: what "does not run" means?

Comment: i think you want setInterval()

Comment: @zerkms well to my knowledge set time outs should call a function every X seconds but it does not it only does it once then never again.

Comment: @Dave: hehe, have you checked [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)? ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [setTimeout vs setInterval again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900262/settimeout-vs-setinterval-again)

Comment: SO is becoming worthless when it comes to Javascript questions regarding JSON, setTimeout and setInterval.  Googling, and/or better yet, learning a little more about the language first, are really in order before blindly posting to SO as though it's your personal help desk

Comment: @GeorgeJempty if you would perhaps use your eye sight better.. this was posted in may. Why are you posting nearly a year later??? Also googling often returns SO as the top result anyway.

Comment: @Dave Needs to be closed regardless, its yet another "I don't understand the difference between setTimeout and setInterval" questions that are *polluting* Stackoverflow.  I've had questions of mine closed after years, so it could happen.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty i often find it easier to understand when i see how it works with my own code over example code that some one else has written.

Comment: @Dave That's no reason to clutter stackoverflow with more and more identical quetions -- and you said *I* should use my eyesight better

Comment: It helped me learn. So it did its purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setInterval)!

Also, it's probably better to pass an actual function in, and you can hold a reference to the loop so you can stop it running later if you want to:

```
var animationLoop = setInterval(function () {
       begin_anim(type, div, marginL);
    }, 1000);

clearInterval(animationLoop); // This would then stop the loop.
```

Comment: But doesnt that mean it will call again even if its not finished yet ?

Comment: @Dave: JS is a single-threaded programming language, and the calls will be queued (it's a bit more complicated, but in this case it's all what you need to know) PS: how it actual works: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: So the only difference is one "waits" then executes.. the other "executures every X ms"

Comment: @phenomnomnominal: you could even return an interval reference from `timeout_begin` (to make an interface a bit more clear)

Comment: @phenomnomnominal how would you stop it ?

Comment: @Dave: if you followed the documentation link I gave in the question comments - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout - you would know it yourself ;-) PS: there are 2: `clearInterval()` and `clearTimeout()` correspondingly

Comment: @phenomnomnominal: at the moment all the 3 arguments will always be of an `undefined` value

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` is supposed to call the function only once.

if you want to call the method repeatedly use `setInterval(function(){}, 1000/*duration*/)`

Answer (score 1):

First, you want `setInterval`, not `setTimeout`

Second, you'll pass a *reference* to a function, not a *call* to a function.  Something like:

```
function timeout_begin(type,div,marginL)
{   
  setTimeout(
    function() { 
      begin_anim(type,div,marginL);
    }, 
    1000
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is only expected to execute the function once after the given timeout. See the documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

You're probably looking for setInterval (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) which executes the code at the interval you set until clearInterval is called.

Comment: w3schools is a terrible resource. Use MDN

Comment: It describes the routine's behavior, describes all the parameters, gives an example, and is easy to find (first result in Google). It seems perfectly sufficient to me, at least for these two specific functions. But if there is a better resource that's certainly good to know.

Comment: For one, they call the first argument "code". That's because they actually used to recommend to pass a string to it. Then, they mention a third argument, lang. I doubt anything but `JavaScript` is supported by anything but IE (which they fail to mention). If a function (not a string) is passed, the argument makes no sense at all. In their `setInterval` example they also assign the return value of `clearTimeout` back to the ID, but their `clearTimeout` documentation never mentions what the return value is. As a side note, `function(){clock()}` could well be replaced by just `clock`.

Comment: I rarely use Javascript, but when I do whatever shows up first in the search results is usually more than sufficient (at least for me) to figure out how to use it. But since I rarely do more than glance at them, I'll trust your judgment and remember your advice to look for an MDN reference instead. ;)